# Move processing to background in android

Tags: android, background

My use case: chat application. The user wants to send an image message to the other user. But the upload process takes a while to the firebase, the user may not stay in that fragment or app till the upload is complete. User may even close the app assuming his/her message will be sent.

Question: How do we guarantee the message delivery after the send button is clicked irrespective of the app is active or inactive.

Comment: do uploading process in a forground service with notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the new WorkManager API.  In their own words - "a library for managing deferrable (meaning it doesn't need to be done instantly) and guaranteed (guaranteed to happen eventually even if app is killed or restarted)"

You should probably still send the instant message using other means though, but the actual uploading of the image can be deferred to the WorkManager.  See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe_yqM16hPQ)